# How to use SQLite via rusqlite from multiple threads?

Tags: sqlite, rust, rusqlite, r2d2

There are a number of articles explaining the problem of multi-threaded access with SQLite but I couldn't find any easy solutions. How does one access SQLite from e.g. a web server where multiple threads work concurrently?

Sources (that still don't explain any easy work-around):

- [SQLite documentation on its modes](https://www.sqlite.org/threadsafe.html)
- [Issue in GitHub to share the connection](https://github.com/rusqlite/rusqlite/issues/188)
- [Reddit post that talks about the same problem](https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/6z7gs2/using_rusqlite_from_multiple_threads/)

Answer (score 5):

You can use `r2d2-sqlite` connection pooling + `std::sync::Arc` to have multi-threaded access to SQLite. Example:

```
[dependencies]
r2d2_sqlite = "0.16.0"
r2d2 = "0.8.8"
```

And in Rust:

```rust
fn main() {
    let sqlite_file = "my.db";
    let sqlite_connection_manager = SqliteConnectionManager::file(sqlite_file);
    let sqlite_pool = r2d2::Pool::new(sqlite_connection_manager)
        .expect("Failed to create r2d2 SQLite connection pool");
    let pool_arc = Arc::new(sqlite_pool);

    let pool = pool_arc.clone();
    whatever.method(move || {
        let connection = pool.get();
        // ...
    });

    let pool = pool_arc.clone();
    whatever.method(move || {
        let connection = pool.get();
        // ...
    });
}
```

Comment: Do you actually need Arc? The example on [the documentation for r2d2_sqlite](https://docs.rs/r2d2_sqlite/latest/r2d2_sqlite/#example) shows it without while working with threading.

Comment: @TrevorVance if something changed and there is now a solution without `Arc`'s, feel free to share! If I remember correctly, in my case, it was not only multi-threaded, but the main thread also would not live long enough and you'd need an Arc or similar. For slightly different constraints, other solutions could be possible as well, so I'm only encouraging to post them

Comment: I would love to. I just don't know that is the case. I am making an assumption based on the documentation. I don't know how to prove it.